# paragraph tag auto generating anchor tag

Tags: html

I have the following code and my paragraph tag that is not wrapped in an anchor tag is auto generating an anchor tag.  The "Connect with us on social media" paragraph is the problem.  It links to a redirect page when inspecting in firebug.  Why is this happening only in this place?  I simply don't want it to be a link.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 social">
    <p>Connect with us on social media</p>
    <p>
        <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/G-S-Masters-Inc/180291982077400" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
         / 
        <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/GSMastersInc" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the css for those classes:

```css
#footer .social {
text-align: right;}

#footer .facebook {
color: #685642;}

#footer .twitter {
color: #685642;}

.col-lg-6 {
width: 50%;}

.col-sm-6 {
width: 50%;}
```

The last two are twitter bootstrap scaffolding classes.  I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie with those.  They apply to different screen resolutions, so it's not duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in html code, if missing `</a>`ending tag at the last of any anchor it will take effect next paragraph as anchor.

before your problematic part you probably mistook to end the previous anchor with `</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally people put anchor tags outside of paragraphs. Don't do this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 social">
<p>Connect with us on social media</p>
<p><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/G-S-Masters-Inc/180291982077400" target="_blank">Facebook</a> / 
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/GSMastersInc" target="_blank">Twitter</a></p>
</div>
```

Instead try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 social">
    <p>Connect with us on social media</p>
    <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/G-S-Masters-Inc/180291982077400" target="_blank">
        <p>Facebook</p>
    </a>
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/GSMastersInc" target="_blank">
        <p>Twitter</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I just revised to include the css. I didn't know css could add anchor tags.

Comment: Okay thats not the problem. I'm going to revise my post and do what I say in my post I think it will work.

Comment: No luck man.  It does the same thing but puts each p on a new line.  It must be a jQuery thing.

Comment: It is definitely not CSS or HTML. jQuery is out of my realm of knowledge though so at least you could rule out that it isn't CSS or HTML.